# Como verificar se há espaços antes, no meio e no final de uma string usando o Regex em C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso verificar com o regex de forma que sejam permitidos apenas Letras e números. Os demais caracteres como ,.-*&%$#@; dentre outros não poderão ser aceitos.
No regex abaixo, estou conseguindo validar isso! Só estou tendo problemas com espaços em branco. No regex abaixo, ele consegue validar os espaços em branco se eu digitar pelo menos uma letra ou número. Ex: 1(espaço) ou (espaço)A. O problema ocorre quando eu digito somente espaços e não digito letras ou números, o regex abaixo não os reconhece. Preciso melhorar o regex abaixo, de forma que ele valide quando eu digitar apenas (espaços em branco)e não aceitá-los, independente da quantidade.

```
protected void ValidarCodigoControle()
{
    RuleFor(p => p.CodigoControle)
        .NotEqual("0").WithMessage("O Código de Controle é inválido.")
        
        .MaximumLength(15).WithMessage("O Código de Controle deve ter no máximo 15 caracteres.")
        .Must(TextoHelper.NaoELetraNemNumeroNemEspaco).WithMessage("O Campo Código de Controle deve possuir apenas letras ou números.");
}


public static bool NaoELetraNemNumeroNemEspaco(string texto)
{
    var rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(texto) ? rg.Match(texto).Success : true;
}
```

Como eu faço isso?

Obrigado :)

Comment: Pra ver se tem espaços no começo, meio ou fim, nem precisa de regex, usar `Contains` é o suficiente. Mas se a regex deve permitir apenas letras e números, então ela não vai permitir espaços. Então não entendi o que vc precisa...

Comment: Aliás, a sua regex atual já funciona, pois ela não aceita espaços: https://ideone.com/EhBxPK

Comment: @hkotsubo essa regex tens problemas ela, ou seja, tem diferenças na verdade ele obriga ser de um jeito, enfim a pergunta ta confusa um pouco.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic No meu comentário acima, o link do ideone é um exemplo em C# com a mesma regex da pergunta. E ela não permite espaços, que pelos comentários eu entendi que é o que ele quer. O único detalhe é que essa regex obriga a ter pelo menos um número (por causa do `\d+`) mas a questão de não aceitar espaço ela já faz. De qualquer forma, continuo sem entender o que a pergunta quer de fato, pois pelo que entendi a regex já funciona...

Comment: @hkotsubo É verdade, Master JR tente editar a pergunta e se possível coloque exemplos do que pode e do que não pode ser aceito.

Comment: Tente postar o local onde você esta validando, veja que mesmo que tenha mais espaços funciona https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kIgHz

Comment: Sim @hkotsubo eu entendo, só estou dizendo que pela pergunta dele está confuso entender, como é complicado entender o que ele quer, tanto que não tem resposta certa para ele ... complicado.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, editei a pergunta...

Comment: Eu acredito que o problema não é o regex e sim onde você esta validando.

Comment: @ Wictor Chaves, estou usando o FluentValidation e chamando uma função para validar com regex. Vou postar o fonte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Verifica se há espaço

Se você quer apenas verificar se há espaço é bem simples, basta colocar na expressão somente o espaço, veja o exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rg = new Regex(@" ");
        if(rg.IsMatch("Hello World")){
            Console.WriteLine("Tem espaço");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Não tem espaço");
        }       
    }
}
```

## Verifica se é valida

Agora se você deseja que não exista nenhum caractere especial e nem espaço você pode fazer desta forma:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if(rg.IsMatch("Hello World")){
            Console.WriteLine("Certo");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Errado");
        }       
    }
}
```

## Verifica se é valida e vazia

No exemplo acima a expressão não aceita vazio, trocando o "+" por "*" é aceito vazio também:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        if(rg.IsMatch("Hello World")){
            Console.WriteLine("Certo");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Errado");
        }       
    }
}
```

> Assim ele vai aceitar letras e números apenas.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Wictor Chaves! Gostaria de validar, na string, se ela contém  apenas letras, números e não contém espaços (no íinício, meio e no fim). Como eu faria isso?

Comment: É este segundo exemplo, mas neste caso ele também não vai aceitar vazio, se você quer que aceite vazio também troque o "+" por "*" que funcionará com vazio também.

Comment: Na vdd, quero que ele aceite apenas letras e números. Não pode conter nenhum caractere especial (Tipo -,$%#@), nem espaço.

Comment: O segundo exemplo faz exatamente isso. Lembrando que se uma string vazia é aceita também você deve trocar o "+" por "*".

Comment: Estou fazendo com sua sugestão ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$. Funciona se eu informar 1 e digitar espaço, ele está validando. Se eu digitar na string dois espaços, ele não valida.

Comment: Só funciona se o espaço for informado no final da string ou no começo... Se eu digitar só espaço, por exemplo, aí validação do regex não pega.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente na sua `regex` coloque o que é obrigatório (números e letras) `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`, exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;       
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");                
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("abcAbc123"));     // true
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(" abcAbc123"));    // false
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("abcAbc123 "));    // false
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("abc Abc123"));    // false
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(" abc Abc 123 ")); // false
        System.Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch("Ab125cAbc123"));  // true
    }
}
```

Online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wV5xYb